# Global Variable Lost

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a global variable which is just a string. I set it when I open Access through AutoExec. This variable is based on whether a bool is true or false which is also a global variable.

Setting the global variable is fine. However I had a error which meant I needed to stop my code and start it again to fix it. This then caused the Global variable to be set to nothing.

Is this normal behavior? I have only just noticed where it is being lost. However it means that if any error does appear and I need to stop my code to fix it. It will get lost every time. And need to close and open it again.

Is there anyway to keep it set until I close Access only?

Comment: Can you trap the error? If so, then you could call the method to set the Global variable again. I have seen this behavior, but that is normally when I manually do something that will cause "memory flush" per say.

Comment: Wouldn't be that easy to trap it as it can occure at any point, it is linked to a SQL server and then doing changes, uploading data, deleting data. So while I have been working on it, it has been doing it at random points. I could try and put some traps in, at the places I think it would fail. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I always recommend the use of Error Handling, even if it a simple Sub. So trapping the error may avoid this problem.

Comment: Just had a thought about error trapping. If you look at my comment to the answer below it might explain a little more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like TempVars have the behavior you want.

These are built-in to Access 2007 and later.

Example (in the Immediate window):

```
Application.TempVars("abc") = 123
? Application.TempVars("abc") 
 123 
? TempVars![abc]
 123
```

These will persist until the application closes, and will survive program resets.

The `SetTempVar` action can be used in your AutoExec macro to set TempVar values.

Comment: That sounds better to use than Global Variables since these can not get reset

Answer (score 1):

It's by design that all variables are reset if the program errors out.

You can force the situation yourself by calling this command:

```
End
```

To avoid the situation, apply error handling wherever you know or think an error can occur.

Also, add a simple function you can call to initialize your global variables during development.

Comment: My autoExec macro gets called at the start which contains the initialisation of the global variable. But with error handling it can cause my program to run for an exceptional amount of time. Do you think the error handling would still be feasable? If you need context read my comment to the answer below. Or do you think trap the error but then restart the code?

Comment: Error handling is always feasable. In fact, it marks the difference between bad or sloppy programming and good programming. During development, of course things may happen - if so, just call your AutoExec macro and continue.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding 4dmonster's answer,

- Create a local table called **tbl_global_variables**.
- Have your settings and its values there.
- Truncate/initialize this table on startup
- Then write function to retrieve value from this table
- In the retrieval function check whether the variable is initialized

the funciton would look like this:

```
Public function FN_GET_GVALUE() as Boolean
    On error goto vError:
    FN_GET_GVALUE = nz(Dlookup("SettingField", "tbl_global_variables"),false)

    Exit function
vError:
    FN_GET_GVALUE = false
End Function
```

every time you want to check the value just ask the system

```
if fn_get_gValue then
    ... do something
end if
```

this way you are safe from loosing global values.. but of course as others said error trapping is a good practice in VBA.

Comment: I would normally put error trapping in, but I since this is incomplete code I am trying to see any errors I get so in future I can place them in traps. Just through me when I could not longer use my global variable since it is nothing. However this looks like a promising way to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Any untrapped error will reset global variables.
May be you can change your code to use a public function instead of a global variable. That function should check if value to return is nothing, and reinit it.

```
Public function JustAString() as string
    static return as string
    if return="" then
        return = SOME calculations
    endif

    JustAString = return
End Function
```

Comment: One of the problems I will have with this is that it can take over 5 mins to run my code as it interacts with SQL Server to then get an error. Which would result in another 5 mins to run again. Another problem is that it also is dealing with temp tables on SQL server which, and usually with an error it closes the connection to the SQL server which then drops the temp table so it would require the whole process to be restarted

Comment: then the only way is to handle all errors. as mentioned in comments